# Jsoup.clean - preserving relative links without base URI

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup 1.13.1 to clean a string to prevent XSS.
I would like to preserve relative links, but can't specify a base URI as there are many domains.
Specifying whitelist.preserveRelativeLinks(true) in this case doesn't make any difference.
I notice that by *removing* protocols from the whitelist I get what I want.
I would like to understand if this has any other side-effects, and would also like to understand why this works.
Below is some code which demonstrates this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<a href=\"https://absolute.link\"></a><a href=\"relativeLink\"></a>";
    Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.relaxed();

    System.out.println("Whitelist.relaxed(): " + Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist));

    whitelist.removeProtocols("a", "href", "http", "https", "mailto", "ftp");

    System.out.println("Protocols removed  : " + Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist));
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Whitelist.relaxed(): <a href="https://absolute.link"></a><a></a>
Protocols removed  : <a href="https://absolute.link"></a><a href="relativeLink"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason why removing protocols from the whitelist works is that it allows relative links to be preserved. When you remove the protocols from the whitelist, you are allowing all protocols to be used in the href attribute of an anchor tag.

By default, Jsoup removes all relative links when cleaning HTML. To preserve relative links, you can use the preserveRelativeLinks method of the Whitelist class1.

However, in your case, you cannot specify a base URI as there are many domains. Specifying whitelist.preserveRelativeLinks(true) in this case doesn’t make any difference.